# Why “di” in “Un bel di, vedremo”?

Tags: word-meaning

I was wondering why “di” is translated as “day” in English in “Un bel di, vedremo”?

Comment: Note that many literal word representations for English speaking audiences, coming from foreign languages, often miss important aspects such as the accented "ì" of "dì" (a literary form of "giorno" - day - in Italian) , which is very different from the normal "i" of "di" ("of"), since English only uses basic Latin characters, except for the rare case of language borrowings (mostly coming from French), like "rosé", "déjà vu", etc. This is unfortunately common for lyrics and music terms that traditionally originate from European countries, using languages that require diacritical marks.

Comment: It's also important to notice that most English readers, not being used to care about diacritical marks, often underestimate or ignore them. The case of "i" is peculiar, because the accent is even more difficult to notice for people that are not used to these aspects. Interestingly enough, the most commonly used accent in Italian is the grave one \` (often called "backtick" when used standalone), usually found at the end of oxytone words ("pietà", "caffè"), indicating an *open* vowel; but "i" is a *closed* vowel, so it could theoretically be written as "dí", unlike the accepted rule of "dì".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the correct spelling is *Un bel **dì** vedremo*, *dì* with the accent,  not *di*.

And *dì* in Italian means *day*.

See
https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/di/

*Di* without accent is the preposition:

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/di1/

Comment: Ho capito. Grazie mille!

Comment: You are welcome!